Get a Message when I start Filezilla
An error occurred saving the transfer queue to "/home/gsp/.config/filezilla/queue.sqlite3".
This all started after a recent upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04.
solved

I would close FileZilla; rename that file to something like queue.sqlite3_TOBEDELETED; and retry.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What error message did you get? Please Edit your question to include this information.
